# Dynamic Dispatch - Template Method in C#

Tags: c#, dispatch

I do not understand why the following output is printed.

Static Type is Base and call to print() and leads to console output:

- Sub1.A
- Base.B

Static Type is Sub and call to print() and leads to console output:

- Sub1.A
- Base.B

Why is here Base.B called and not Sub.B?

Static Type is Sub and call to B() leads to console output:

- Sub1.B

The hidden Function B() on Sub is called in the program. But not if I call it with print().

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{                
            Base b = new Sub();
            Sub s =  b as Sub;

            b.print(); //See first paragraph with 2 bullet points
            s.print(); //See second paragraph bullet points
            s.B(); //See third paragraph with bullet points

}

public class Base
{
        public Base() {}

        public void print()
        {
            A();
            B();
        }

        public virtual void A() { Console.WriteLine("Base.A"); }

        public void B() { Console.WriteLine("Base.B"); }
}

public class Sub : Base
{
        public Sub()  { }

        public override void A() { Console.WriteLine("Sub1.A"); }

        public new void B() { Console.WriteLine("Sub1.B"); }
}
```

Comment: The new keyword only hides an existing method, it doesn't replace it. When you call `print` in your base class, the base class has no idea that there's another method on `Sub` that hides `B`, and it calls the `B` it is aware of existing.

Comment: But with the virtual keyword it has to look in the virtual calling table and finds the Sub.A? This table then is initialized during construction at runtime?

Comment: 10.6.3 of the spec has this to say: "In a virtual method invocation, the run-time type of the instance for which that invocation takes place determines the actual method implementation to invoke". I don't actually know the implementation details behind that, but the section of the spec on virtual methods (10.6.3 in the version shipped with Visual Studio) seems to have a lot of the information you may be looking for.

Comment: According to that:
In a non-virtual method invocation, the compile-time type of the instance is the determining factor. 

Thanks for the hint with the spec :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in how each method is called from each place, and it comes down to differences between `new` and `virtual`/`override`.

First the theory, an oversimplified explanation of both keywords:

- `new` just defines another method in a derived class with the very same name of an existing method in a base class "hiding" it. The choice of what method to call (base or derived) is took at **compile time**, based on the type of the reference used to call the method.
- `virtual` indicates that a method could have an alternative implementation in a derived class and in such case it should be used instead. Here the choice is made at **runtime** based on the type of the actual object.

Now applying it your case.
All calls to `A` are exactly the same here, since it's virtual and the only instance lying around is of type `Sub`. Dynamic dispatch does its thing and this result in a call to `Sub.B` as you've found.

But the calls on `B` are on two places. The one inside the `print` method and other on `main` directly. As `B` isn't `virtual` it uses static dispatch and the **compile time** type of its reference to determine the call site. The one from `main` is easy enough to see why it uses `Sub.B`. The other within the `print` method however doesn't uses the same references, they call an instance method within the same class using the `this` pointer implictly. It's totally equivalent to writing this:

```
public void print()
{
    this.A();
    this.B();
}
```

So the call to `B` depends entirely on the compile time type of `this`, that is `Base` in this case (as it's written in that class). So `Base.B` is invoked here.

The fact that the previous call to `print` came from another type of variable is irrelevant here, as that's only used to determine what `print` implementation to take (here we have only one), but whatever actions are done by the method itself are beyond that and therefore don't influence its behavior.